# Swift reading data in Firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a barcode scanner on my app, and when the app has scanned a barcode I want it to search through my Firebase database to see if it has been scanned before.

So this is my Firebase database JSON:

```
{
  "Ingredients" : {
    "Pork" : {
      "Products" : {
        "5741000124024" : {
          "Amount" : "1",
          "Unit" : "kg"
        }
      }
    },
    "apple" : {
      "Products" : {
        "5826374655024" : {
          "Amount" : "200",
          "Unit" : "g"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`5741000124024` is the barcode of the product I'm trying to find by this code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Ingredients").queryEqual(toValue: code).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

    if !snap.exists() {
        print("Not scanned before")
    } else {
        print("Found It")
    }

})
```

It keeps printing `Not scanned before`, even though the barcodes match up, What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change your structure to match what you are doing.

```
Ingredients
   -Uiiais9jjasd
     type: -Yss9ks9slkls
     barcode: "009012398129"
     amount: "1"
     unit: "kg"
   -Yijaijisdja
     type: -Y89u9s9asdsd
     barcode: "099009298493"
     amount: "1"
     unit: "kg"
   -Ua9j9jisjijd
     type: -Y89u9s9asdsd
     barcode: "000192983982"
     amount: "22"
     unit: "kg"

Types
   -Y89u9s9asdsd
     type: "Pork"
   -Yss9ks9slkls
     type: "Apple"
```

The node key names (-Uiiais9jjasd, -Yijaijisdja) are created with childByAutoId as it's usually best practice to disassociate your key names from the child data.

Comment: I can't do that, because there are different types of lets say pork, there a 2kg package a 0.5kg package and so on which all have different barcodes, So it need to be structured that way

Comment: @Benja0906 Gotcha. I updated the answer to accommodate all ingredients and all types (Pork, Apple etc)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new node/branch for easy fetching of data if your existing nodes are quite complex to extract some data from, like so:

```
{
  "Barcode-Products" : {
    "5826374655024" : {
      "parent-item-id" : "apple"
    }
  },
  "Ingredients" : {
    "Pork" : {
      "Products" : {
        "5741000124024" : {
          "Amount" : "1",
          "Unit" : "kg"
        }
      }
    },
    "apple" : {
      "Products" : {
        "5826374655024" : {
          "Amount" : "200",
          "Unit" : "g"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the link of this JSON I made using online editor: 
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ad884a350ce65b1580e090eb044002b1

This is a technique you want to use in NoSQL / Firebase. In this case, you can easily use Firebase SDK's **queryEqual to** function to fetch a specific **Barcode Id**. Then look up its **parent-item-id**.

Comment: While on the surface this structure looks ok, it's going to hard to maintain. It needs to be denormalized and having a sub-node Products under apple is reversed - apple IS a kind of product, not the other way around. The biggest issue is disassociating keys with the data they contain. This answer won't work as the parent-item-id "Apple" is not going to match "apple". Yeah - it's a typo but highlights a fundamental issue; what if you *want* to use Apple instead of apple? Every reference in the entire structure to apple would have to be updated. Using an childByAutoId key avoids that entirely.

Comment: Hi Jay, yes, it's a typo. I was doing this answer while at work. Of course the key/id should be from childByAutoId. Yes, you're right, every reference in the entire database should be updated.